# How to automatically resize widgets when you click window maximize/minimize button?

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt5, qt-designer

I would like to resize automatically the widget size based on the window size.

For example: If the window size increases also the widget inside the window have to increase.

[image] [image]

Where can I insert the codes? Can I also edit in Qt designer?

```
import psycopg2
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
import sys

try:  # Establishing the connection
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                              password="admin",
                              host="127.0.0.1",
                              port="5432",
                              dbname="database")
    cursor = connection.cursor()  # create a cursor
    class login(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):  # call the inherited classes
            super(login, self).__init__()
            uic.loadUi('login/login.ui', self)
            self.btnLogin.clicked.connect(self.login)  # login button
            self.btnCancel.clicked.connect(self.cancel)
            self.show()
        def login(self):  # login button
            auser = self.entryUsername.text()  # entry username from postgresql
            apass = self.entryPassword.text()  # entry password from postgresql
            aname = self.entryName.text()  # name from postgresql
            sql_select_admin = """SELECT aid, auser, apass, aname FROM admin WHERE auser = %s and apass = %s """
            cursor.execute(sql_select_admin, (auser, apass,))
            record = cursor.fetchall()
            myid = 0
            self.entryName.setText(" ")
            for row in record:
                myid = row[0]
                self.entryName.setText(row[3])
            if auser == "" and apass == "":  # if username and password are empty
                confirmation = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self.parent(), "Warning", "Please enter Username and Password!",)
                self.entryUsername.setFocus()
            elif auser == "":  # if username is empty
                confirmation = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self.parent(), "Warning", "Please enter Username!",)
                self.entryUsername.setFocus()
            elif apass == "":  # if username is empty
                confirmation = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self.parent(), "Warning", "Please enter Password!",)
                self.entryPassword.setFocus()
            else:
                if myid == 0:
                    confirmation = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self.parent(), "Warning",
                                                             "Your Username and/or Password was Incorrect!",)
                else:
                    confirmation = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self.parent(), "Information",
                                                             "Your Account is Verified!",)               
        def cancel(self):  # cancel button
            cancelconfirmation = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self.parent(), "Cancel", "Are you sure you want to Cancel?", QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes, QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
            if cancelconfirmation == QMessageBox.Yes:
            self.close()
            sys.exit()
            else:
            return

except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
    print("Error while connecting to PostgreSQL", error)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    lw = login()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: See [using layout managers in Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html).

Comment: Is there any link/site you can give aside from that? Because I already tried that one .

Comment: that's sufficient, you only need to work with it and get experienced enough. Ensure that you set the layout for the central widget (right click on an empty area outside any other widget/layout, and set the proper layout from the "Lay out" submenu).